# Upgrading From ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis - class java.util.ArrayList is not a valid property type

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am upgrading ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis while maintaining client code. I have multiple places code looking like this.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

public class TestV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root.xml");
        JmsTemplate jms = ctx.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(10);
        ids.add(20);
        map.put("ids", ids);
        map.put("updated", true);

        jms.convertAndSend("mytest", map);

    }

}
```

How do I fix below error coming from above code.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQPropertyConversionException: class java.util.ArrayList is not a valid property type
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at com.mycompany.adhoc.TestV.main(TestV.java:33)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQPropertyConversionException: class java.util.ArrayList is not a valid property type
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1404)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1437)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1324)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1981)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:288)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:223)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:241)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:634)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:608)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
```

In ActiveMQ "Classic" we can set trusted packages in connection factory. How do I do it in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with setting the trusted packages on the JMS `ConnectionFactory`.

The problem is that your application is implicitly using this [JMS "extension"](https://activemq.apache.org/structured-message-properties-and-mapmessages) provided by ActiveMQ "Classic." As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/structured-message-properties-and-mapmessages) states:

> This JMS extension feature allows you to attach Map and List properties to any JMS Message **or to use nested Maps and Lists inside a MapMessage**. [emphasis mine]

When you pass the `Map<String, Object>` variable `map` to [`JmsTemplate.convertAndSend`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#convertAndSend-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) it uses the default [`SimpleMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/SimpleMessageConverter.html) to convert that `Map` into a [`javax.jms.MapMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html). As the JavaDoc for `MapMessage` states:

> The names are String objects, and the values are **primitive data types** in the Java programming language. [emphasis mine]

In other words, according to the JMS specification the values in the `MapMessage` can only be primitive data types. However, ActiveMQ "Classic" provides an extension which allows using `List` implementations. Code which uses this extension is not portable to other JMS brokers since it does not adhere to the JMS specification. This is why ActiveMQ Artemis throws the error `ActiveMQPropertyConversionException: class java.util.ArrayList is not a valid property type`.

You will either have to change your application code to adhere to the JMS specification (i.e. use primitive data types in the values of your `Map`) or this same extension will have to be implemented by ActiveMQ Artemis.